# Can i construct a string_view from a nullptr?

Tags: c++, string, view

I just found that xcode/clang does not allow to construct a std::string_view from a char* nullptr. I would expect that this sets size() to 0 and returns a null for data(), and this is how also how gcc 7.2 on my Ubuntu Linux box implemented it.

I checked http://en.cppreference.com/ but couldn't find any comment about this, so what is the standard saying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, yes and no. You cannot pass a null pointer to `std::string_view`'s constructors, because that will violate their preconditions; see constructor 2 and 3 in [[string.view.cons]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.view.cons).

But `std::string_view`'s default constructor sets size to zero and null for its data, so you will have to use that constructor instead, or use this workaround/trick:

```
std::string_view().swap(your_string);
```

Comment: You are pointing to "[str, str + traits​::​length(str)) is a valid range."  but this doesn't help here. [nullptr,0] is for sure a valid range. So it's all depends on the standards definition of traits::length, where can i find this ?

Comment: @Lothar You might know that `std::string_view` is just an alias to `std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>>`. That second parameter are the traits. It doesn't seem to say what should happen if `i` is out of range, so I'm just assuming that it isn't valid [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/char.traits.require#tab:char.traits.require)

Comment: There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0903r0.pdf) to allow `nullptr` as single constructor argument for both `basic_string_view` **and** `basic_string`.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl Jup, but the committee couldn't reach a consensus on it though. I think it will appear again at the next one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can simply do `your_string_view = {};` instead of the swap-trick.

Comment: @Brandlingo: it would really nice if std committee would allow the nullptr to pass to string_view. Now you have to explicitly check for that.

Comment: "see constructor 2 and 3 in [string.view.cons]" implies that constructor 3 also requires non-null pointer. However, the constructor is 'constexpr basic_string_view(const charT* str, size_type len);'; and its precondition is only '[str, str + len) is a valid range', which allows nullptr with 0 length. (Unless "2" and "3" point not to related constructors, but to clauses there? In which case my comment is irrelevant.)

Comment: Well, I just successfully initialized `std::string_view` with nullptr `const char* const` pointer with MSVC 2022 v17.2.0 preview 2.1 (latest as of 24.03.2022)